# Trying to use HTML5 and Javascript within Ember, Starfield component

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ember.js

I made a basic starfield program that loads into a canvas using javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/vLfG2/

I've been trying to incorporate it into an ember site by putting the canvas onto a page, but I'm not sure how to load the program in. I've tried including the code into the page's router, controller, load it from a separate file, etc. Not really sure where to go from here. Any pointers?

I assume I can just use...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </script>
</head>
<body>

...

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="starfield">
  <canvas id='c'></canvas>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For the HTML.

And then...

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {

this.route('starfield');

});
```

for the app file. But where do I put the star field's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Now that I see what you're trying to do, I'd totally componentize it

```
 App.StarFieldComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  tagName:'canvas',
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  starCount:100,
  refresh:30,
  attributeBindings:['width', 'height'],
  stars:null,
  on:false,

  build: function(){
    var canvas = this.$()[0],
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        stars = [],
        height = this.get('height'),
        width = this.get('width');

    for (var i = 0, len = this.get('starCount'); i < len; i++){
      stars.push([Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height, Math.random() * 2, 0.5 + Math.random() / 2]);
    }

    this.set('stars', stars);
    this.set('ctx', ctx);
    this.set('on', true);
  }.on('didInsertElement').observes('starCount', 'width', 'height'),

  kill: function(){
    this.set('on', false);
  }.on('willDestroyElement'),

  clear: function () {
    var ctx = this.get('ctx'),
        height = this.get('height'),
        width = this.get('width');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  },
  drawStars: function () {
    var stars = this.get('stars'),
        starCount = stars.length,
        ctx = this.get('ctx');
    for (var i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 0, ' + stars[i][3] + ')';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(stars[i][0], stars[i][1], stars[i][2], 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
  },
  moveStars :function (e) {
    var stars = this.get('stars'),
        starCount = stars.length,
        height = this.get('height'),
        width = this.get('width');;
    for (var i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {
        if (stars[i][1] - stars[i][2] > height) {
            stars[i][0] = Math.random() * width;
            stars[i][2] = Math.random() * 2;
            stars[i][1] = 0 - stars[i][2];
            stars[i][3] = 0 + Math.random() / 2;
        } else {
            stars[i][1] += e;
        }
    }
  },
  gaze: function(){
    if(this.get('on')){
      this.loop();
    }
  }.observes('on'),
  loop: function () {
    if(!this.get('on')){
      return;
    }
    var refreshRate = this.get('refresh');
    this.clear();
    this.moveStars(3);
    this.drawStars();
    Em.run.later(this, this.loop, refreshRate);
  }

});
```

And then in a template you can insert remove super easily

```
{{star-field width=300 height=200 starCount=20}}
{{star-field width=400 height=200 starCount=500 refresh=10}}
{{star-field width=100 height=100}}
{{star-field}}
```

Static variables: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yaxoweya/8/edit

Bound variables: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yaxoweya/9/edit

### Original answer (not really applicable, but good info nonetheless)

For the model, you would set up a route matching your router's name.  If your route is a noun, generally you use `this.resource`, if it's a `verb` you use `this.route`

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('starfield')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

#### Route for the particular route in your app

```
App.StarfieldRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model:function(){
    return {apple:'cow'};
  }
});
```

#### Controller for wrapping your model, and interacting with the view/template

```
App.StarfieldController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  foo:'bar'
});
```

#### View for dom interaction

```
App.StarfieldView = Em.View.extend({
  click: function(){
    alert('you clicked this view!');
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nodojasu/3/edit

Comment: Not sure how to insert my original code though to animate the canvas. When I paste it in then it gives tons and tons of errors.

Comment: What's your original code look like, when does it need to be executed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vLfG2/ is the working star field and I wanted it to execute on the page loading.

Comment: Updated with how I'd recommend doing it, you probably could optimize, monkey some stuff around, but it should show you the idea

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, this really opens a lot of doors for me!